# Grab lines in file and prepend file with portion of line

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terminal, grep

I am looking for a way to read lines in a file that match a specific string get the rest of the string, and append it to the same file that was read.

So I am looking to turn this:

```
// MARKER: hello world
var x = 32;
// MARKER: meow meow
var v = x + 1
// MARKER: foo bar
var f = 'a'
```

To this:

```
hello world
meow meow
foo bar
// MARKER: hello world
var x = 32;
// MARKER: meow meow
var v = x + 1
// MARKER: foo bar
var f = 'a'
```

I'd like to match any line containing `// MARKER:` get the rest of that portion and prepend the file with it.

I would like to do this to a whole folder of files recursively.

Comment: So what have you tried? Looks like you can use `sed` to filter out the MARKER: lines and remove `// MARKER: ` lines and print them, then append the whole (unchanched) file after that. Something like `sed '/.../s/.../.../' file; cat file;`

Comment: Did you arrive at a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution. Uses `sponge` from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) to read/write from same file:

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0 -I {} bash -c "grep -Po '(?<=MARKER: ).*' '{}' | \
cat - '{}' | \
sponge '{}'"
```

With the following data:

```
$ find -type f
./some/dir/structure/data
./data

$ cat data
// MARKER: hello world
var x = 32;
// MARKER: meow meow
var v = x + 1
// MARKER: foo bar
var f = 'a'

$ cat some/dir/structure/data
// MARKER: cow
var x = 1;
// MARKER: dog
var x = 2;
// MARKER: cat
var x = 3;
```

Result:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c "grep -Po '(?<=MARKER: ).*' '{}' | cat - '{}' | sponge '{}'"

$ cat data
hello world
meow meow
foo bar
// MARKER: hello world
var x = 32;
// MARKER: meow meow
var v = x + 1
// MARKER: foo bar
var f = 'a'

$ cat some/dir/structure/data
cow
dog
cat
// MARKER: cow
var x = 1;
// MARKER: dog
var x = 2;
// MARKER: cat
var x = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, this `sed` one-liner would do:

```
sed -E -n 's/^\/\/ MARKER: (.*)/\1/p' file;cat file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Provide path of directory as command line arg.
for file in $(find $1 -type f); do { 
    echo $file;
    prefix=`(grep "// MARKER: " $file | sed 's;// MARKER: ;;g')`
    # Adding prefix to file
    echo -e "$prefix\n$(cat $file)" > $file
}
done
```

save this script into a file eg. replace.sh

```
$ bash replace.sh path/to/the/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's#^// MARKER: (.*)#\1#p;$!d;e cat file' file
```

Use pattern matching to print the parts that match at the front of the file. Then append the whole file using the `e` command in sed, that evaluates the following command.